# Minimum action test for Intent-Filter in android

Tags: android, intentfilter

What is the minimum number of actions an Intent-Filter may have? If I specify no action in the filter, will the component be executed, or it will fail the test.

I was reading API Guides for android and I came across this line which is a bit confusing for me...

> "If the filter does not list any actions, there is nothing for an
>   intent to match, so all intents fail the test. However, if an Intent
>   does not specify an action, it will pass the test (as long as the
>   filter contains at least one action)."

Can someone explain what happens if no actions are specified in the filter. Thanks.